# How to perform delete operation on multiple products with different ids on jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I have multiple products (for ex: 20) of different ids, and i want to perform delete operation on all 20 products using jmeter.
Note: the ids are not in numbers like (1,2,3...) where adding concurrency thread group will solve it, but here i have different ids which includes alphanumeric in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put these IDs into a CSV file and read it using [CSV Data Set Config](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config), with default settings each thread (virtual user) will read next value from the CSV file on next iteration.

The below setup will read all the values from the CSV file and stop the test when it will reach the last entry in the file

[image]

The value will be kept in `ID` [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) so you will be able to refer it as `${ID}` where required, i.e. in [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler

More information: [Using CSV DATA SET CONFIG](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733689-Using-CSV-DATA-SET-CONFIG)